# What is the most efficient way to compare keys of two HashMaps?

Tags: java, performance, hashmap

I want to compare 2 HashMaps to sum the values for any common keys between them:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> map1
HashMap<Integer, Integer> map2
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Could you show us your current (maybe) not-so-efficient solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Get the keySet of both maps (`O(n)`).
2. Compute the intersection among them (`O(n)`).
3. For the common keys found in above set, get the values from both maps and sum them (`O(n)`).

Total time complexity - `O(n)`.

```
Set<Integer> commonKeys = new HashSet<>(map1.keySet());
commonKeys.retainAll(map2.keySet());

Map<Integer, Integer> result = commonKeys.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), 
                    k -> map1.get(k) + map2.get(k)));
```

Comment: Note that this also destroys `map1`. `.keySet()` returns a backing keyset. Any removal done to it will also remove the k/v pair in the original map. Use `map1Keys = new HashSet<>(map1.keySet());` if you don't want to destroy the map pointed at by `map1`.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Missed that point. Thanks for pointing it out.